# TouchEvent cancelled in TextView in ScrollView

Tags: android

I have a layout with a TextView in a ScrollView because scrolling in the TextView doesn't work well and I have a custom ActionMode in addition to the default txt ActionMode and scrolling in the textview directly for some reason destroys my ActionMode.
However, my Problem:

In my app you can make selection in the text and edit those selections later, I implemented these selections myself since the 'normal' selection mode doesn't work (no handles on selections that were set programatically...!?) When I edit a selection it works as long as the text is not scrolled (i.e. the top line is on top of the scrollview). When the text is scrolled, the selection works as long as I stay in the same line. Once I go up or down, the TextView's onTouch gets a 'cancel' event and the OnTouchListener of the ScrollView is called...

1) Why does the TextView's MotionEvent get cancelled?

2) Is there a way I can prevent it? Maybe tell the ScrollView to ignore everything for the time I'm editing the selection?

3) Is there a way I can map the coordinates that I get in the ScrollView's onTouch to coordinates in the TextView?? (So I could at least dispatch the event to the txt view and 'pretend' as the 'cancel' never happened....

Any ideas???
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.
I implemented my own ScrollView where I overwrite [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and return false while the textView is being edited...